# Set theory exercise with universal set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of a universal set $U$. Show that:

$ A\subseteq B ⇔ A' \cup B = U$

Does anyone happen to know how to prove this correctly? I am struggling with this, as I cannot make anything sensible out of this.
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$\Rightarrow$" of course $A'\cup B\subseteq U$ by definition so we only need to show the opposite inclusion. Assume $u\in U$. We have two cases

1. $u\in A$. Then $u\in B$ by "$A\subseteq B$" assumption and thus $u\in A'\cup B$.
2. $u\not\in A$. Then $u\in A'$ and so $u\in A'\cup B$

Both give us $U\subseteq A'\cup B$.

---

"$\Leftarrow$" Let $a\in A$. Since $a\in U$ then $a\in A'\cup B$. But $a\not\in A'$ by assumption. Thus the only possibility is that $a\in B$ and so $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just have one more question, those arrows you wrote "⇐" and "⇒" how exactly do you read them, I mean how that divides the statement above? (I do not know if that's what they are meant to do). Just need small clarification.

Comment: @georgyhere these are left and right implications. Together they form "if and only if" you want to prove.